# JPA: Update mapping table alone

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Project and Employee entities, which has ManyToMany relationship like below.

```
@Entity
public class Project {
     @Id @GeneratedValue
     private int projectId;

     private String projectName;

     // has some additional columns

     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
     private List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee> ();
     ....
     .....

 }


 @Entity
public class Employee {
     @Id @GeneratedValue
     private int id;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;

     @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project> ();

     ....
     ....
}
```

When I use above entities, JPA create a mpping table 'Employee_Project' like below.

```
create table Employee_Project (emp_id integer not null, projects_projectId integer not null)
```

My question is, whenever new employee is added, I want to update both employee table and Employee_Project mapping table only, assume I know project id that I would like to map this employee to. (without touching project table/entity, I mean why should I provide complete project object, while saving employee entity alone, how can I do this via jpa?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide the entire `Project` object. Use `EntityManager.getReference(projectId)` or `JpaRepository.getOne(projectId)`.

Those methods will create a proxy object with the appropriate id, rather than loading the entire `Project` entity from the data store.

EDIT Your service method should look pretty much like the following:

```
@Transactional
public void createEmployee(Employee employee, Long projectId) {
    employee.setProjects(List.of(projectRepository.getOne(projectId));
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

As a side note, `CascadeType.ALL` (in particular, because it includes `CascadeType.MERGE` and `CascadeType.REMOVE`) doesn't make sense for `@ManyToMany`. Unless you're planning to create a `Project` by creating an `Employee`, `CascadeType.PERSIST` makes no sense, either.

Comment: I used 'EntityManager.getReference' method to get Project proxy object and attached this to new employee object. When I try to store this new Employee object, I am getting error like org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()

Comment: You do have a transaction around your service method, right?

Comment: Crizzis, my question is different. I am asking, Can I update entity  (Employee) and mapping (Employee_Project_mapping) )table alone instead of updating other entity table (Project), whenver new employee onboarded and mapped to some existing project.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand that. Do you have a transaction around your service method? You should have one, otherwise the solution won't work for you